# Show an popover for 3 second on added row in table in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I want to do: I have table bound by ngRepeat to a collection from the controller in angularJs. When I add an item trough collection.unshift(newItem), in the controller, I want that a popover shows up over the first column of the newly added row.

How I try to achive this:

```
 <table> 
      <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
         <td>
           <a popover-on-show>{{item.Name}}</a>
         </td>
       </tr>
 </table>
```

and the directive:

```
.directive('popoverOnShow', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.popover({
                    trigger: "manual",
                    html: true,
                    content: "This is a new added item",
                    placement: "right"
                }).popover('show');
                $timeout(function () { element.popover('hide'); }, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
```

problem is, when I do in the controller on init:
    $scope.items = resource.query();
the popover is shown on all items for a second, how can I tell the directive to not show the popover on initial load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, but it seems for me to be totally wrong, so I would appreciate a better solution. What I did is setting in the controller a *initializing* property and checking it in the directive.

Snippet from controller:

```
$scope.refresh = function () {
    $scope.initializing = true;
    $scope.projects = null;
    someResource.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
        $scope.projects = result;
        $timeout(function () { $scope.initializing = false; });
    });
}
```

Directive:

```
  .directive('popoverOnShow', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (!scope.$parent.$parent.initializing && scope.$first) {
                    element.popover({
                        trigger: "manual",
                        html: true,
                        content: "<div>Just added this item</div>",
                        placement: "right"
                    });
                    $timeout(function () { element.popover('show'); });
                    $timeout(function () { element.popover('hide'); }, 3000);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call show during the link function, it will show as the directive is linked. I'd recommend using a watch to show a popover during runtime.

Something like:

```
scope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // Do nothing during initial run
    if (newValue != oldValue){
        if (<isLastElement>){
            <showPopover>
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried to add this $watch in the link function, both, on _item_, and _items_ but in both cases I got newValue==oldValue when adding a new item. So it never gets into the block.